# How to install DHCP server on FreeBSD 7.2?

Tags: dhcp, freebsd

I have a clean install of FreeBSD 7.2-RELEASE. I want to install a simple DHCP server for a few windows computers. But, unfortunately, following don't work:

```
pkg_add -r isc-dhcp3-server
```

Error is: "Error: FTP Unable to get ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-7.2-release/latest/isc-dhcp-server.tbz"

What i'm doing wrong? pkg_add -r nano works just fine :(. Is a DHCP server package has different name? Or it must be fetched from another place? Or in 7.2 isc-dhcp3 is not used and it's some other way to run a simple DHCP server?

I know that it's possible to build it from ports (theoretically), but i'm very interested in how to install it as a package from internet. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way more programs you can find in FreeBSD's ports collection. First you need to checkout ports.

```
portsnap fetch extract
```

then ones a day/week/month you should run `portsnap fetch update` to update collection (not programs them selfs)

After ports are extracted you can find one you want and install it:

```
cd /usr/ports
make search name=isc-dhcp
cd /usr/ports/net/isc-dhcp31-server
make install clean
```

PS. And it'll be good to [read handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/ports.html) first

Comment: The original question specifically stated that they didn't want to use ports (and the binary packages are built from ports, anyway).

Comment: Because for 7.2-release there is only isc-dhcp3-devel is accessible via packages that is in unstable branch at that time. And stable release 3.1.2p1_1 can only be accessible via ports.

Comment: So, basically, FreeBSD 7.2-RELEASE is not so 'RELEASE' since it is missing required packages?

Comment: There is always something that you can't install from packages, so you need to use ports instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try pkg_add -r isc-dhcp31-server

Comment: Same error - 'unable to fetch' :(.

Comment: as you can see here ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-7.2-release/Latest/ the only available is isc-dhcp30-devel.tbz

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to download this package: ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/packages/net/isc-dhcp31-server-3.1.2p1_2.tbz and install it:

```
# pkg_add -v isc-dhcp31-server-3.1.2p1_2.tbz
```

?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the mirror is broken. Like @SaveTheRbtz try updating the ports tree. If that doesn't work, you can always manually fetch the file, and then copy (just google for it) and then place it in the right folder (usually /usr/ports/distfiles).